# Populating UITableView row 0 static and the rest with NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In one section of my app I have a `UITableView` which is working fine right now.  I would like to set row `0` `cell.textLabel.text` to `@"Some string"`.  Once row `0` has been set I would then like to load the rest of the rows from an array.  Currently on load my array populates the table view but I'm trying to set row `0` as a *sticky*.  The closest example I can think of is a forum topic that is set to stay at the top.  My array is constructed of returned data from a web service call.

It's been a while since I've messed with table views, and I'm having a blank on this one. 
The table view is 1 section, and I get the rows by counting the elements in the array.  Since I would like to create an additional cell (row `0`) I would call `[array count] + 1`.  I don't know if this approach is the best one which is why I'm reaching out to the community here.

Any insight or a shove in the right direction would be great at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count]+1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        // Code for first
        [[cell  textLabel] setText:@"First cell"];
    } else {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]-1]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the top of your table to be "sticky", why not consider using that string as a section header or title?  In this case, the header stays visible at all times until the next section (e.g. if you had two sections, that is) is fully on the screen.

In any event, in one of my current projects I'm required to do roughly the same thing that you're doing and I have a static string being returned in row 0 (which scrolls off the top of screen when the table view scrolls down).

And in my UITableViewDataSource method, I always add one for the static cell to the number of objects in my array and in my "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method, I increment the row by one when the indexPath.row is not zero.  And if it is zero, I return my static string.

And dark_knight provides some nice sample code that illustrates what I was describing to you.  So +1 to him/her.